# Redirection Htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I try to make a redirection from a dead link to a new one.

source https://www.gillespaulesnault.com/esnault%20painting/html/bluenote.htm

target https://www.gillespaulesnault.com/project/blue-note-a-la-huchette/

1st solution

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^esnault%20painting\/html\/bluenote.htm 
    https://www.gillespaulesnault.com/project/blue-note-a-la-huchette/ [R=301,L,NC]
    </IfModule>
```

2nd solution

```
    Redirect 301 ^esnault%20painting\/html\/bluenote.htm https://www.gillespaulesnault.com/project/blue-note-a-la-huchette/
```

Can't make it works. Thank you

Comment: Any entries in your http server's error log file? Is the rewriting module loaded at all? What response do you get instead of the expected one? Are you sure you are not looking at client side cached results? And _please_ add a clear description of what you actuall try to achieve. Just the two (often missleading) terms "source" and "target" are _not_ enough ...

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `RedirectMatch`:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^esnault%20painting\/html\/bluenote\.htm$ https://www.gillespaulesnault.com/project/blue-note-a-la-huchette/
```

Read more about it: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch